# what are differences between metric space and metric linear space?

Tags: functional-analysis

A metric linear space is a linear space equipped with metric but i want to know the point wise differences between metric space and metric linear space.Can any body write it down in points?

Answer (score 4):

A metric space can be any set, with or without an additional algebraic structure.

In a metric linear space $X$ there is a close connection between the distance and the linear algebraic structure:

1. The distance is translation invariant: $d(x+a,y+a)=d(x,y)$ for all $x,y,a\in X$. This implies that the sum is a continuous function from $X\times X$ to $X$.
2. The map $\mathbb{R}\times X\colon\to X$ that takes $(\lambda,x)$ to $\lambda\,x$ is continuous.

For instance $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear metric space with euclidean distance. The sphere $\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ is also a metric space with the same distance, but is not a linear space.

Comment: AFAIK, "metric linear space" usually implies that the metric is translation invariant.

Comment: Yes, I did not realize that.

Comment: can u tell me example of metric linear space.

Comment: Examples: 1) $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $d(x,y)=\bigl(\sqrt{x_1^p+\dots+x_n^p}\bigr)^{1/p}$, $1<p<\infty$. The case $p=2$ is the Euclidean metric. 2) The space $C([a,b])$ of continuous functions on a compact interval with the uniform distance $d(f,g)=\sup_{a\le x\le b}|f(x)|$.