# If $\nu(Y) < \infty$ then $F: X \to L^0(Y), x \mapsto f(x, \cdot)$ is $\mu$-measurable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ be complete $\sigma$-finite measure spaces,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $Z := X \times Y$,
- $\mathcal C$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$,
- $\lambda$ the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$,
- $(Z, \overline{\mathcal C}, \overline{\lambda})$ the completion of $(Z, \mathcal C, \lambda)$.

For $\delta >0$ and $f,g \in L^0 (Y)$, we write
$$
\begin{align*}
\{|f - g| > \delta\} &:= \{y \in Y : |f (y) - g(y)| > \delta\}, \\
\nu (|f - g| > \delta) &:= \nu (\{|f - g| > \delta\}).
\end{align*}
$$

For $f, g \in L^0 (Y)$, we define
$$
\hat \rho (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \nu (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}.
$$

Then $\hat \rho$ is an [extended pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Metric_space#Generalizations_of_metric_spaces) on $L^0 (Y)$. For $f_n, f \in L^0(Y)$, we have $\hat \rho (f_n, f) \to 0$ IFF $f_n \to f$ [in measure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions), i.e.,
$$
\nu ( |f_n - f| > \delta) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
\quad \forall \delta >0.
$$

I'm trying to prove an analogue of the main result in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756754/assume-fx-cdot-in-lp-textloc-y-for-a-e-x-in-x-then-the-map) thread, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $f:Z \to E$ be $\lambda$-measurable. Then
>
> 1. For $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ we have $f(x, \cdot) \in L^0 (Y)$.
> 2. If $\nu(Y) < \infty$ then $F: X \to L^0(Y), x \mapsto f(x, \cdot)$ is $\mu$-measurable.
> 3. The map $G: X \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}, x \mapsto \hat \rho(f(x, \cdot), 0)$ is $\mu$-measurable.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

We need the following result, i.e.,

> [Lemma](https://mathoverflow.net/a/452953/477203) Let $f \in S (Z)$ and $\varepsilon>0$. There is $f_\varepsilon \in S(Z)$ of the form
> $$
> f_\varepsilon (x, y) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} e_{i,j} 1_{A_{i}} (x) 1_{B_{j}} (y)
> $$
> such that
>
> - $(A_{i})_{i=1}^{n}, (B_{j})_{j=1}^{n}$ are measurable partitions of $X,Y$ respectively,
> - $e_{ij} \in E$ and $\mu(A_i)+\nu(B_j) < \infty$ for all $i,j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$,
> - $\|f-f_\varepsilon\|_{L^1(Z)} < \varepsilon$ and $\lambda (\{f \neq f_\varepsilon\}) < \varepsilon$.

There is a sequence $(g_n) \subset S(Z)$ such that $g_n \to f$ $\lambda$-a.e. For each $n$, let $f_n$ be the approximating function of $g_n$ given by **Lemma** such that $\lambda (\{f_n \neq g_n\}) < 2^{-n}$. It's easy to verify that $f_n \to f$ $\lambda$-a.e.

1. I [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753759/almost-everywhere-convergence-in-product-measure-and-that-in-coordinate-ones) that for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ we have $f_n (x, \cdot) \to f(x, \cdot)$ $\nu$-a.e. Let
   $$
   f_n (x, y) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{\varphi_n} e_{n, i,j} 1_{A_{n, i}} (x) 1_{B_{n, j}} (y).
   $$

Clearly, $f_n (x, \cdot) \in S(Y)$. Then for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ we have$f(x, \cdot) \in L^0(Y)$.

2. We define
   $$
   F_n: X \to L^0(Y), x \mapsto f_n(x, \cdot).
   $$

Then $F_n \in S(X, L^0(Y))$. For $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ we have $F_n (x) \to f(x, \cdot)$ $\nu$-a.e. We have $\nu(Y) < \infty$, so $\nu$-a.e. convergence [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754912/if-for-a-e-x-in-x-the-sequence-f-nx-cdot-n-is-cauchy-in-l1-y-t) that in $\hat \rho$. Then for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ we have $\hat \rho (F_n (x), F(x)) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$. The $\mu$-a.e. limit of a sequence of $\mu$-measurable functions [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507762/generalize-a-theorem-about-the-mu-measurability-of-a-mu-a-e-limit-of-a-se) again $\mu$-measurable. The second claim then follows.

3. There is a countable measurable partition $(Y_n)$ of $Y$ with $\nu(Y_n) < \infty$ for all $n$. Let $f_n:X \times Y_n \to E$ be the restriction of $f$ to $X \times Y_n$. Then $f_n$ is measurable. We apply part (1) and get that
   $$
   F_n: X \to L^0(Y_n), x \mapsto f_n(x, \cdot)
   $$
   is measurable. Then
   $$
   G_n: X \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \hat \rho(f_n(x, \cdot), 0)
   $$
   is measurable. We have $G(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty G_n (x)$ for all $x\in X$. Then $G$ is measurable.

Comment: $L^0$ is not a Banach space, not even a normed vector space. I don't really think that bochner measurability makes sense then.

Comment: @PhoemueX $(L^0(Y), \hat \rho)$ is a [metric linear space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179742/1019043) and we con define the notion of Bochner measurability as in the case of Banach space...

Comment: @PhoemueX A map being Bochner measurable just means that it is a a.e. limit of a sequence of simple functions. I could not see any difficulty preventing us to define Bochner measurability for functions taking values in $(L^0(Y), \hat \rho)$.