# Topology of convergence in measure is not compatible with the vector space structure of measurable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ be complete $\sigma$-finite measure spaces,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $Z := X \times Y$,
- $\mathcal C$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$,
- $\lambda$ the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$,
- $(Z, \overline{\mathcal C}, \overline{\lambda})$ the completion of $(Z, \mathcal C, \lambda)$.

For $\delta >0$ and $f,g \in L^0 (Y)$, we write
$$
\begin{align*}
\{|f - g| > \delta\} &:= \{y \in Y : |f (y) - g(y)| > \delta\}, \\
\nu (|f - g| > \delta) &:= \nu (\{|f - g| > \delta\}).
\end{align*}
$$

For $f, g \in L^0 (Y)$, we define
$$
\hat \rho_Y (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \nu (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}.
$$

Then $\hat \rho_Y$ is an [extended pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Metric_space#Generalizations_of_metric_spaces) on $L^0 (Y)$. For $f_n, f \in L^0(Y)$, we have $\hat \rho_Y (f_n, f) \to 0$ [IFF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754273/convergence-in-a-complete-measure-is-metrizable) $f_n \to f$ [in measure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions).

**My understanding** It seems to me $(L^0 (Y), \hat \rho_Y)$ is *not* necessarily a [metric linear space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179742/1019043) because scalar multiplication is *not* necessarily continuous in the topology induced by $\hat \rho_Y$. Take $E=Y = \mathbb R$ and $\nu$ its Lebesgue measure. Let $f_n := 1$ and $\lambda_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$. Then $|\lambda_n -1| \to 0$ and $\hat \rho_Y(f_n, 1) =0$. However,
$$
\hat \rho_Y (\lambda_n f_n, 1) = \hat \rho_Y \bigg (\frac{1}{n}, 0 \bigg) = +\infty.
$$

> Could you confirm if my above understanding is fine?

Comment: You posted essentially [the same question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453338/the-set-of-measurable-functions-together-with-convergence-in-measure-is-a-comple) (always include links if you must do that!)  I commented there, pointing out the error that $\hat{\rho}_Y(1/n, 0)$ is not $+\infty$ but rather $1/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nate mentioned in his comment, my calculation is wrong. Indeed, $\hat{\rho}_Y(1/n, 0) = 1/n$. However, I have found a new counter example.

---

Let $f_n(x)=f(x)=x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $\lambda=0$. Then for all $\delta>0$,
$$
\mu\left(\left|\lambda_n f_n-\lambda f\right|>\delta\right)=\mu(\{x \in \mathbb{R}:|x|>n \delta\})=+\infty.
$$